# reCaptcha calls recaptcha__en,js multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

So,

I was experiencing this behaviour in one of my projects so I decided to try the google recaptcha exemple code to try to figure out what is wrong.

The code is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        var widgetId1;
        var widgetId2;

        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
            'sitekey' : 'My-Site-Key'
        });
        widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render('html_element2', {
            'sitekey' : 'My-Site-Key'
        });
    };
</script>

<form action="javascript:alert(grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId1));">
    <div id="html_element"></div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="getResponse">
</form>
<br>
<!-- Resets reCAPTCHA widgetId2 upon submit. -->
<form action="javascript:grecaptcha.reset(widgetId2);">
    <div id="html_element2"></div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="reset">
</form>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
</script>
```

Even with this example code from google docs the page is still calling the same file recaptcha__en.js multiple times.

Is anyone experiencing this?
Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of what is happening:
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys5Ob.jpg)

EDIT 2:

Here is a jsFiddle with the example code and example site keys:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h7rnqbn/)

Comment: When you say 'calling' you mean it requests and downloads the file twice, or once per captcha? Are the URLs identical - they don't e.g. include a timestamp or your different API keys? Are the responses identical?

Comment: @Rup
Yes, in the network tab you can see the page requesting multiple times the same file. Even with the code I posted(which is the exemple code from google) it still requests the file multiple times. Plus the requests come from the api.js of the recaptcha(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js)

Comment: @Rup hey, I edited the post and included a screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still an issue and I'm experiencing the same behaviour. multiple calls to download recaptcha__en from different initiators.
have you find anything to fix/handle it?